# Creating a column with a slice of other column's values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I would want to create a column that has the values of another column, but in a way that the new column's (B) values start from a specific part (in the example from the fourth value) of the original column (A). It would look something like this:

```
index  A       B
0      73      290
1      90      9
2      38      38
3      290     29
4      9       etc
5      38      ..
6      29      ..
etc    etc     ..
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please tag with the programming language or technology you're trying to achieve this in.

Comment: That is a very good point, I am using python!

Comment: Please [tag your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) with Python. To tag your question, edit your question and type in "python" next to where it says calculated-columns, then click on the box that says python, then click save. Also, if you are using pandas, you might want to tag with that too, and possibly dataframe tag.

Comment: @vivi Let me know if the solution solved your query or you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done simply by using ***label-based*** or the ***integer-based*** indexing methods `loc` and `iloc`. You should look at the official [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-integer) to learn more about them. They can provide a range of useful operations.

In your example, since the 4th value will have index position as `3`, you should do:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].loc[3:].reset_index(drop=True)

>>> df
index    A      B
    0   73  290.0
    1   90    9.0
    2   38   38.0
    3  290   29.0
    4    9    NaN
    5   38    NaN
    6   29    NaN
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use `pandas.DataFrame.shift` method to achieve this. It shifts indexes by desired number of points/periods. Read about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

So since you need to fill column `B` starting from 4th value in `A`, you will have to shift column `A's` values `3` indexes up. You can achieve it like this:

```
>>> df['B'] = df['A'].shift(-3)
>>> df
index    A      B
    0   73  290.0
    1   90    9.0
    2   38   38.0
    3  290   29.0
    4    9    NaN
    5   38    NaN
    6   29    NaN
```